# What require magic is happening in rails here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I started Rails without NO fundamental Ruby knowledge.

and now i'm here in `require, load, include, extend questions`

I have learned that if it is a separated file

in Ruby, you MUST contain `require or load` 'file path'

If it is like this, in my `application_controller` there needs to be a bunch of requires,

if i want to `include` bunch of helpers.

ex>

```
require 'path_to_the_helpera.rb'
require 'path_to_the_helperb.rb'
class ApplicationController < ActionController:Base
  include HelperA
  include HelperB
end
```

But as you all know, no `require` is in Rails app(except external library in `lib` folder)

I'm assuming that inside `config` folder will do this magic....it is pretty hard for a noob like me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails adds a `const_missing` hook so that when you reference an unloaded constant it will first try and load it for you instead of raising a NameError.

There is a [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) with an extensive discussion of how it does this, pitfalls and tips but the main thing is that you need to name things inline with the conventions, ie a class or module called `FooBar` should be in foo_bar.rb in one of the folders in rails' search path.

Comment: awesome!! i was looking for this!

Answer (score 2):

> I started Rails without NO fundamental Ruby knowledge.

This is definitely not the best approach.

Rails heavily uses conventions. Therefore, if you place an helper in the `/app/helpers` folder, and you name it according to the conventions, it will be automatically loaded and included in your app.

For instance

```
# file /app/helpers/foo_helper.rb
module FooHelper
  def print_foo
    puts "foo!"
  end
end
```

Now you can simply call `print_foo` in a view, and it will work.